# email form will not send email. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, html, email

I know this question has been asked before, but I have checked the solutions/answers on here and they do **not work for me**.

Originally the problem was that my server didn't have php installed, so when I pressed 'submit'  code would show up....Now it's installed and it's running smoothly now.  But my email form won't send...it leads to a blank screen and I keep getting an error in the console which says:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" which is pointing to myserver/html_form_send.php

part of html:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <label for="Upload">Upload a CV</label>
</td>
 <td valign="top">
<input type="file" name="selectedfile" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "myemail@email.com";

    $email_subject = "email subject";


    function die($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        die('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    die($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: open your html_form_send.php file directly in the browser and see what you get there.

Comment: Why?  I just see code if I open it directly in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

local webserver or live host on the interwebs? If this is a local webserver then I'd suggest you need a mailserver running in order to actually send emails ( you can get a free mail server from Pegasus - http://www.pmail.com/downloads_s3_t.htm - it's called Mercury Mail )

If it is a live server on the interwebs try sending a basic example email using the standard code found in the php manual - if that works then the problem is the code above

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change "display errors" level, and see what is the error. But I think the problem is that you try to re-declare "die" function:

```
function die($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
```